# HTML CSS Drag bar slide at the top to display more information

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I want a bar that would be present on the bottom of the screen and when clicked, it slides up to display some more detailed information, then it can be clicked again to slide back down. It is very hard to explain!

This is a picture displaying it. When this is clicked I want to slide it up and fill the screen (kinda like an overlay) with information about your order (e.g where the price comes from) then it can be clicked again to slide back down.

[image]

I am not sure what this is called hence I am having trouble finding something similar! Thus links to something like this are very much appreciated. Please help if you can. Thank you.

Comment: What is the question? are you just trying to find what this style of element is called? Or are you looking for a library that does it for you? (Both of those are relatively off topic for StackOverflow, but we may be able to point you to an alternative site) If you want to make an attempt at building this yourself we will happily help with any issues you run into if you include the code in the question.

Comment: Basically what would be the best approach to do this, an example or link to something similar would answer my question!

Comment: I would have look at using `fixed` positioning, relative to the bottom of the viewport (e.g. `bottom: -90px` would hide most of a 100px high element off screen). Then you could have a toggle-able class that adjusts the bottom offset to 0 (or more) to make things visible.

Comment: @DBS Height of a section like this would likely be either variable or may contain a scrollable area. I think using `top` would be better since we know the height of the visible area at all times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of component is normally seen in mobile apps.

It can be implemented in web apps using vanilla javascript. All you need is a absolutely positioned element that is moved up when clicked.

```js
const slider = document.querySelector('.slider');
const sliderHead = document.querySelector('.slider .head');

slider.addEventListener('click', () => {
  slider.classList.toggle('slideUp');
});

// initially, only show slider head from the bottom of the page
function setSliderPosition(slider) {
  let sliderPaddingTop = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(slider).paddingTop);
  const offset = slider.offsetHeight - sliderHead.offsetHeight - sliderPaddingTop;
  slider.style.bottom = `-${offset}px`;
}

setSliderPosition(slider);
```

```css
p, h2 { margin: 0; }
body { overflow: hidden; background: #eee; }

.slider,
.slider::before {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.slider {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 80%;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: bottom 0.4s ease;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.slideUp {
  bottom: 0 !important;
}

.slider::before {
  content: '';
  background: #eee;
  width: 75px;
  height: 5px;
  top: 8px;
}

.head {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div class="head">
    <h2>Your Order</h2>
    <span>$123</span>
  </div>
  <div class="moreInfo">
  <h2>
   More Information:
  </h2>
    <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create this effect easily with jQuery and CSS, just create a card and its parent overflow hidden, then move card on click as per your need.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
            $('.bar').click(function(){
                $('.card').toggleClass("showMe");
            });
        });
```

```css
.wrapper {
            overflow: hidden;
            height: 175px;
            width: 200px;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            position: relative;
        }
        .card {
            position: absolute;
            top: 75%;
            transition: top 0.5s;
        }
        .card.showMe {
            top: 10px;
        }
        .shownInfo {display: flex;justify-content: space-between;}
        .bar {
            height: 8px;
            width: 50%;
            border-radius: 5px;
            background-color: #333;
            margin: 0 auto; 
      cursor: pointer;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="shownInfo">
            <p>Your order</p>
            <p>$123</p>
        </div>
        <div class="additionInfo">
            <h2>Show whaterve you want here.</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This would fall under the category of "off-canvas models", where you create a div with class, say `.order-summary`, and set it up with:

```css
.order-summary {
  position: fixed;
  top: calc(100vh - 80px);
}
```

Here in the calculation for `top`, the `80px` being subtracted is the visible height of the div as per your screenshot (you can update the exact height, I'm just using a rough estimation).

You can have a button to toggle the `top` property with simple JavaScript.